# How do I compile gnu libstdc++.a with PIC?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

I'm trying to compile a shared library for systems that don't have a libstdc++ new enough to run it, which means I need to statically link libstdc++ into the library. I'm trying to link directly to libstdc++.a (`-Wl,-Bstatic -L/path/to/lib64 -lstdc++`), but I'm getting an error that seems to indicate that my libstdc++.a wasn't linked with PIC:

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib64/libstdc++.a(compatibility.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `typeinfo for __cxxabiv1::__forced_unwind' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
lib64/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

I tried recompiling GCC with CFLAGS="-fPIC" and CXXFLAGS="-fPIC", but that didn't seem to do anything.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to pass `--with-pic` option to the `configure`. GCC build is a very complex beast with multiple stages, so simply passing a CFLAGS variable may not work as intended.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere? It's not on http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: But if you change into <gcc>/libstdc++-v3 subdirectory and run `configure --help` there you will see it.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28811 - the pic issue with stdc++ libs has a fairly turbulent history.

Answer (score 0):

Reading [GCC configure documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html). I used this flag `--enable-host-shared` when building `GCC` as it said in the description:

> Specify that the host code should be built into position-independent
>   machine code (with -fPIC), allowing it to be used within shared
>   libraries, but yielding a slightly slower compiler.